# Best practice for managing context saves with MagicalRecord?

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord-2.1

I just downloaded the latest version (Developer) from MagicalRecord to fix a few warnings I got when validating my app's latest update.

I now find that **MR_saveNestedContexts** is deprecated, and is replaced by **MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)**.

This seems to be a lot of code to write to save each change/addition to the Core Data store; I have 17 different places in my app where I use **MR_saveNestedContexts**.  My thoughts were to create a method and pass it the parameters, based on [this article from Loriot](http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/#sthash.zAMhQqSR.PEJEwBfG.dpbs).

While thinking about this, I was wondering if there was such a thing as "best practices" for MR?

Comment: `MR_saveNestedContexts` just calls `MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil`, so if you don't *need* the completion handler, you could just find/replace it at 17 places.

Comment: That's what I figured, but wasn't sure... what about "best practices" for MR?  Is there such a thing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything special for MR. You have to decide how to handle errors such as a failed save, but I cannot give general advice on that. It really depends on the application if you want to report such an error to the user, or just NSLog it.

Comment: @Martin R: please re-write your comment as an answer... SD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot give general advice how to handle Core Data save errors. Depending on the
data and the application, it might make sense to report a failure to the user, or 
display a "failed" status in some UI element, or just `NSLog` it.

In the simplest case, you could replace `MR_saveNestedContexts` by 
`MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil`, and use the MagicalRecord error handling
methods (`setErrorHandlerTarget:action:`) to report or log the error.